# How can I access my Gunicorn served Flask app from the web?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, flask-restful

Regarding the following documentation:

> Gunicorn¶ Gunicorn ‘Green Unicorn’ is a WSGI HTTP Server for UNIX.
>   It’s a pre-fork worker model ported from Ruby’s Unicorn project. It
>   supports both eventlet and greenlet. Running a Flask application on
>   this server is quite simple: gunicorn myproject:app Gunicorn provides
>   many command-line options – see gunicorn -h. For example, to run a
>   Flask application with 4 worker processes (-w 4) binding to localhost
>   port 4000 (-b 127.0.0.1:4000):
>   `gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:4000 myproject:app`

This is all and well, however, the documentation does not say how to configure port 4000 to be accessible from the web.

I want to be able to handshake something like the following,

```
www.mysite.com:4000
```

And get back a response.
My app works fine on Flask’s development server and Gunicorn locally. I just can’t figure out how to configure it to work on my cloud instance so I can make posts and gets.

Comment: Make sure you the firewall allows traffic through 4000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to make gunicorn available over the web. Instead you are supposed to use it with a reverse proxy, such as nginx.

The gunicorn docs have a [full example](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html) of configuring nginx to reverse proxy to your gunicorn process.

Comment: Thanks. Will investigate. New to this.